# Java multi-Module (jar dependecies) with only one property file

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, properties

I have my spring java proyect with several multimodules that will be compiled as jar files that will be included in the main module.

|-- Module1
|-- Module2
|-- Module3
.
.
|-- MainModule

The module1, 2 and 3 will be compiled as jar files included in Main module.
The point is that in each module a have a "application.property" file to use @Value annotation.
The point is that I would like to have only one "application.properties" file that will include all properties of the module to centralize such properties and not have to be opening each properties file to change them.

is this possible? and How can i do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should write a maven or ant task that concat all application.properties together in the main module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `maven-antrun-plugin` to run ant [concat task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html). Something like below should work.

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <concat destfile="${project.build.directory}/application.properties">
                    <fileset file="${project.basedir}/../module1/src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                    <fileset file="${project.basedir}/../module2/src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                    <fileset file="${project.basedir}/../module3/src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                </concat>
            </target>

        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry for not answer you but it works perfectly thanks!